# IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-cloud

I'm trying to run simple app using Eureka server. But I get exceptions:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
>   start embedded Tomcat Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
>   start embedded Tomcat Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]
>   failed to start

EurekaApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8080

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-beta-3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you confirm the Java version you are using please.

Comment: @0xadecimal, java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Spring 5, Spring Boot 2 and Spring Cloud 2.x require java 8

Comment: @spencergibb, I changed java to java 8, but exception is the same...

Comment: Please provide the full exception